# Building subversion 1.6.12 - make: *** [subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la] Error 1 - Solaris 10 Sparc

Tags: svn, solaris, sparc

I get the following while trying to compile subversion 1.6.12 from source on Solaris 5.10 SPARC platform. I only need the svn client program on this machine so no need for Apache, Neon or Swig.

My configure:

> $ ./configure --without-berkeley-db --with-zlib=/usr --without-sasl
>   --disable-nls --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr --without-apxs --without-swig --without-neon --with-ssl --prefix=/var/tmp/subversion/svn
>
> $ make
>
> cd subversion/libsvn_subr && /bin/bash
>   /var/tmp/subversion/subversion-1.6.12/libtool --tag=CC --silent
>   --mode=link gcc
>   -g -O2  -g -O2  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib  -rpath /var/tmp/subversion/svn/lib -o libsvn_subr-1.la  atomic.lo auth.lo c
>   ache-inprocess.lo cache-memcache.lo cache.lo checksum.lo cmdline.lo
>   compat.lo config.lo config_auth.lo config_file.lo co nfig_win.lo
>   constructors.lo ctype.lo date.lo deprecated.lo dirent_uri.lo dso.lo
>   error.lo hash.lo io.lo iter.lo kitchensi nk.lo lock.lo log.lo
>   macos_keychain.lo md5.lo mergeinfo.lo nls.lo opt.lo path.lo pool.lo
>   prompt.lo properties.lo quoprin t.lo sha1.lo simple_providers.lo
>   skel.lo sorts.lo sqlite.lo ssl_client_cert_providers.lo
>   ssl_client_cert_pw_providers.lo  ssl_server_trust_providers.lo
>   stream.lo subst.lo svn_base64.lo svn_string.lo target.lo time.lo
>   user.lo username_provide rs.lo utf.lo utf_validate.lo validate.lo
>   version.lo win32_crashrpt.lo win32_crypto.lo win32_xlate.lo xml.lo
>   /usr/local/a pr/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lgdbm -ldb-4.2 -lexpat -liconv
>   /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -luuid -lsendfile -lrt -lsocket -lnsl 
>   -lpthread  -lz  -lsqlite3 -lsocket make: *** [subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la] Error 1

It seems to me that subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la do not exist.

> $ ls subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la
>   subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la: No such file or directory

Any clues? Help greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I managed to solve this compile error by adding:

export LDFLAGS="-L /usr/local/lib -R /usr/local/lib -L /usr/sfw/lib -R /usr/sfw/lib -L /usr/lib -R /usr/lib"

and also adding to configure:

--enable-shared=yes --enable-static=no --disable-nls --without-serf

export LIBS="$LIBS -lintl"

However I get a new one now:

ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib: unknown file type
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to .libs/svn
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subversion/svn/svn] Error 1

Comment: Do you have any specific needs that you have to compile Subversion yourself?  If not, perhaps you can just download a ready package from OpenCSW.

Comment: No I do not have any specific reason on why to compile it by myself, I just had a hope that it would be quite simple to do. Instead I installed CollabNet SVN client which worked like a charm, http://www.collab.net/subversion . Thanks for the tip on OpenCSW, I haven't looked into that site before!

Answer (score 0):

The .la related errors are occurring [quite often](http://wiki.opencsw.org/porting-faq#toc2) when building Solaris packages.  I'm not a libtool expert, so I don't know the details, but I know that at OpenCSW it's common to use [a script](https://gar.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gar/csw/mgar/gar/v2/bin/fixlibtool) which removes libtool's pseudo libraries from the build.